# How to hide if text attribute value = blank?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript

Script:

```
<div class="shipout">
<p style="margin:0;">Delivery: FAST & FREE</p>
<script>
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
  var dat = new Date(this.valueOf());
  dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
  return dat;
}

var dat = new Date();

document.write('Between ')
document.write(dat.addDays(<?php echo $_product->getData('shipout_day_from');?>))
document.write(' & ')
document.write(dat.addDays(<?php echo $_product->getData('shipout_day_to'); ?>))
</script>
</div>
```

Output:

```
Delivery: FAST & FREE
Between Sun Mar 19 2017 06:35:17 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) & Mon Mar 20 2017 06:35:17 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

How to hide the front end output if the attribute `shipout_day_from` is blank?

Comment: you want to hide attribute based on which value? shipout_day_from or shipout_day_to ?

Comment: shipout_day_from

Comment: I post answer. check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your code in condition,

```
<?php if($_product->getData('shipout_day_from')){ ?>
    <div class="shipout">
    <p style="margin:0;">Delivery: FAST & FREE</p>
    <script>
    Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
      var dat = new Date(this.valueOf());
      dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
      return dat;
    }

    var dat = new Date();

    document.write('Between ')
    document.write(dat.addDays(<?php echo $_product->getData('shipout_day_from');?>))
    document.write(' & ')
    document.write(dat.addDays(<?php echo $_product->getData('shipout_day_to'); ?>))
    </script>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do code like this.

```
<?php if($_product->getData('shipout_day_from') != '' && sizeof($_product->getData('shipout_day_from')) > 0) : ?>
<div class="shipout">
    <p style="margin:0;">Delivery: FAST & FREE</p>
    <script>
    Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
      var dat = new Date(this.valueOf());
      dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
      return dat;
    }

    var dat = new Date();

    document.write('Between ')
    document.write(dat.addDays(<?php echo $_product->getData('shipout_day_from');?>))
    document.write(' & ')
    document.write(dat.addDays(<?php echo $_product->getData('shipout_day_to'); ?>))
    </script>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```